# DataTables.net columns.width doesn't work

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using https://datatables.net plugin to show a table.

I want to change first column width as wide as possible.

But column width doesn't change when I configure it as below manual:

https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.width

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
            "columnDefs": [
                { "width": "50%", "targets": 0 }
            ]
    } );
} );
```

I have created JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/AntonyBaasan/btjg433y/2/

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You just need to add  this line to increase width of the columns according to your self.**

```
   <th style="width:500px">Name</th>
```

Comment: This works, thank you @iqbal. But, I would like to control width from JavaScript. Because eventually, I want to get each column dynamically (which will provide width).

Answer (score 0):

set the width of table

```
<div id="divexample" style="overflow-x: auto"> 
<table id="example" style="width: 500px;" >
    <thead>
        <!--Header row-->
        <tr>

         </tr>
    </thead>
    <!--Data row-->
    <tbody>

    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry @Mannan, it is not working. Can you show it on the JsFiddle (or some other tools)?